# Laravel resource: How define the name of the key parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

When you define a resource with `Route::resource('recipe', 'RecipeController');`, among others, the following route is defined: `/photo/{photo}/edit`, and once you define all your resources you have something like this:

- `/recipes/{recipes}/edit`
- `/allergens/{allergens}/edit`
- `/ingredients/{ingredients}/edit`

Because all my records use `id` as primary key (MongoDB), I'd like to have `{id}` instead, like so:

- `/recipes/{id}/edit`
- `/allergens/{id}/edit`
- `/ingredients/{id}/edit`

I dug in the `Router` class but I don't see how to specify this.

More over when I create a form with `Form::model($record)` I get actions like `/recipes/{recipes}` because `recipes` is a property of `$record`.

How can I define the name of the *key* parameter to `id` instead of `recipes`, `allergens`, `ingredients`?

Comment: So are you concerned about the routes or in fact the form builder?

Comment: I'm more concerned about the routes, I would like them to follow the same pattern. e.g. `{resource}/{id}/edit`

Comment: There you go then. Have in mind nested resources though - like in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the param name for `Route::resource`, you need custom `ResourceRegistrar` implementation.

Here's how you can achieve that in a shortest possible way:

```php
// AppServiceProvider (or anywhere you like)
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar', function ($app) {

    // *php7* anonymous class for brevity,
    // feel free to create ordinary `ResourceRegistrar` class instead
    return new class($app['router']) extends \Illuminate\Routing\ResourceRegistrar 
    {

      public function register($name, $controller, array $options = [])
      {
        if (str_contains($name, '/')) {
          return parent::register($name, $controller, $options);
        }

        // ---------------------------------
        // this is the part that we override
        $base = array_get($options, 'param', $this->getResourceWildcard(last(explode('.', $name))));
        // ---------------------------------

        $defaults = $this->resourceDefaults;

        foreach ($this->getResourceMethods($defaults, $options) as $m) {
          $this->{'addResource'.ucfirst($m)}($name, $base, $controller, $options);
        }
      }
    };
  });
}
```

Now your routes will look like:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', ['param' => 'some_param'])
/users/{some_param}

// default as fallback
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController')
/users/{users}
```

**Mind that this way can't work for nested resources** and thus they will be a mix of default and custom behaviour, like this:

```
Route::resource('users.posts', 'SomeController', ['param' => 'id'])
/users/{users}/posts/{id}
```

Comment: I was hoping for something easier like this: https://github.com/ICanBoogie/Routing#defining-resource-routes-using-routemaker with `OPTION_ID_NAME`, but your code will do just fine. Thanks a lot Jared!

Answer (score 6):

I know this is 4 year old question but for anyone who is googling; you can pass a third argument to override key naming:

`Route::resource('ingredients', 'IngredientController', ['parameters' => ['ingredients' => 'id']]);`

Or

`Route::resource('ingredients', 'IngredientController')->parameters(['ingredients' => 'id']);`

[See Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your ids to the routes you don't necessary need to change the parameters {recipes} to {id} since the parameters are just a placeholder.

So

```
 public function edit($recipes){
    // code goes hr
 }
```

is the same as this

```
 public function edit($id){
    // code goes hr
 }
```

for this route `/recipes/{recipes}/edit`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the issue is also with `Form::model`, because the `recipes` property is not available in the record, I end up with `/recipes/{recipes}` routes. I updated my original post.

Comment: Oh ok you are using route model binding i guess.

Comment: @olvlvl It doesn't matter what is in route as oseinow says it's just a placeholder. I think the problem is somewhere else. Anyway, what is the error you are having after submitting the form?